# What are types of exceptions in PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have WPF application. There is textbox with only number validation. I want to disable validation messages in debug output. The messages like this

> System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '0adsf' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=Age; DataItem='MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=41560081); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='ValidatedTextBox'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

I have found next solution

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Clear();
    }
}
```

But I have no idea which other types of message can be affected. I was looking for more information about

> PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource

But msdn says

> Gets a data-binding trace source.

Common guys...

The question is what are types of message will be disabled with those code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against disabling WPF tracing altogether, it can be quite valuable when tracking down subtle binding issues. I don't know what all the types are but definitely binding failures and a lot of other things regarding control initialization, visual and logical trees etc.

I recommend you write your own converter for your case and manage your conversions and conversion errors that way. And you can disable WPF tracing from the IDE/debugger.